# Xslt 1.0 if element value from a node is true then grab the value of another element from the same node

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

This source XML has is the short version of the big one. The  is empty in the first node but do have values in the next nodes. I want to generate an XML file to show the value of  in the  tag of the output XML.This value will stay the same for the whole source XML file and also for the output XML.

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
   <companyCode>002</companyCode>
   <transportation>
      <express>
         <revenue>
            <rateSourceCode></rateSourceCode>
         </revenue>
      </express>
   </transportation>      
   <transportation>
      <express>
         <revenue>
            <rateSourceCode>REBS</rateSourceCode>
         </revenue>
      </express>
   </transportation>
   <transportation>
      <express>
         <revenue>
            <rateSourceCode>REBS</rateSourceCode>
         </revenue>
      </express>
   </transportation>
   <system>     
      <engineName>OR</engineName>    
      <activityCc>1000</activityCc>
      <transactionName>RB</transactionName>
   </system>
   <system>    
      <engineName>OB</engineName>
      <activityCc>1001</activityCc>
      <transactionName>RI</transactionName>
   </system>
</root>
```

I tried using the for-each loop but that prints the tag multiple times but I only need it one time. Is there any way to use a for-each loop with kind of break statement so if I use if condition and if it meets the condition and then not print the lines multiple times.

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Delivery class="entity">
    <top>REBS</top>
    <System class="entity">
        <a>OR</a>
        <b>1000</b>
        <c>RB</c>
    </System>
    <System class="entity">
        <a>OB</a>
        <b>1001</b>
        <c>RI</c>
    </System>
</Delivery>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following.

> XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <Delivery class="entity">
            <top>
                <xsl:value-of select="(transportation/express/revenue/rateSourceCode[. != ''])[1]"/>
            </top>
            <xsl:for-each select="system">
                <System class="entity">
                    <a><xsl:value-of select="engineName"/></a>
                    <b><xsl:value-of select="activityCc"/></b>
                    <c><xsl:value-of select="transactionName"/></c>
                </System>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Delivery>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, this work even if the the source xml has node value on different position. Thanks a bunch